# How can I make JavaScript calls to scrape data from a website?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

*I'll try to explain everything the way I understand it as clearly as possible, so correct me if I'm confused with something.*

I was trying to scrape the users from a member list on a website, I used Python and the first thing I did was making a post request to the Request URL with the required headers so I get a response that contains the data I need but this didn't work, so I tried to find out the reason.

From what I understand now the website uses AJAX to make XHR and JavaScript calls which respond with the content (users).

The JS code is stored on a static website from what Chrome's developer tool request initiators
tell me ([Here is an image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xREEg.jpg)), which responds with the [HTML that contains the users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxTwd.jpg)

The idea is to create a script that runs this static JS script that's stored online and fetch the data about the users from it. ([Image for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leCDn.jpg))

How do I achieve this, I'm using python. What libraries do I need etc.? Any help/advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not quite right. You will want to run a headless browser that will render the remote page after running all it's scripts the same way they would in a regular browser and give you an API to extract what you need to python. I don't do much with python to know best one to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your questions, I think you're trying to load data from a website that uses AJAX to load data.

In my opinion, have a look at Scray and some Headless Browers.

Check the flowing links for more information

- https://scrapy.org/
- https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer
- https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer